# Filter out information that is not required in an http request in ionic 2 App

Tags: javascript, ionic2

I want to filter out the information that is not required on a http.get to save space in my sqlite db and just in general not have a great deal of saved data I will never use.

http.get

```
    platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.http.get('https://www.reversegeocoder.com/api/v1/yoursecretapikey/lsd')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe (data => {
            let lsd_info = data;
            console.log('lsd Fetch', lsd_info);
        });           
    }
```

Response from server (can be even larger)

```
[
  {
    "query": "1-6-67-13 W4",
    "response": {
      "status": "ok",
      "err": [],
      "lat": 54.763928,
      "lng": -111.96659,
      "latlngms": "54° 46' 50\" N, 111° 58' 60\" W",
      "country": "Canada",
      "province": "AB",
      "city": "Lac La Biche",
      "street": "9116 95 Street",
      "street_prox": 23,
      "near": {},
      "address": "9116 95 Street, Lac La Biche, AB",
      "lld": "1-SE-6-67-13-4",
      "lsd": "1-6-67-13 W4",
      "lsd_ra": "",
      "uwi": "",
      "nts": "",
      "nts_border": [],
      "utm": "12N 437807E 6068951N",
      "utm_v": "Zone 12, 437807 meters easting, 6068951 meters northing (Northern Hemisphere)"
    }
  }
]
```

I would like to filter out most data and use only "lat": 54.763928, "lng": -111.96659, as an example so I can then save only this info to the sqlite db.

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? If you only want the `lat` and `lng` then just save those, what's the problem? Also, this has nothing to do with typescript, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: I was asking how exactly would I just save those.  I tried                     let lsd_info = data.response.lat;        to just save the lat.  I am unsure of how to grab certain parts of that Array and save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code I guess that something like:

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.http.get('https://www.reversegeocoder.com/api/v1/yoursecretapikey/lsd')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe (data => {
        let lsd_info = {
            lat: data[0].response.lat,
            lng: data[0].response.lng
        };
        console.log('lsd Fetch', lsd_info);
    });
}
```

or this:

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.http.get('https://www.reversegeocoder.com/api/v1/yoursecretapikey/lsd')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .map(res => { return { lat: res.response.lat, lng: res.response.lng } })
    .subscribe (data => {
        console.log('lsd Fetch', data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks you have been a great help.  One day I hope to return the favor